# full width query and shrinking

Tags: html, css

In this one page site my  aboutus and contact are not taking full width and height which i need.anymore suggestions are more welcomed.how to shrink top nav bar when about service and contact page comes.

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Scrolling Nav (http://startbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2013-2016 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE)
 */

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/* Demo Sections - You can use these as guides or delete them - the scroller will work with any sort of height, fixed, undefined, or percentage based.
The padding is very important to make sure the scrollspy picks up the right area when scrolled to. Adjust the margin and padding of sections and children 
of those sections to manage the look and feel of the site. */


.about {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#000026;
    color:white;
   
    
}

.services{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#000026;
    color:white;
    
}

.contact {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#000026;
    color:white;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ITspectra</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/carousel-3d.js" ></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
    background-color: tan;
    float:left;
  }
  /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color:black;
      width:100%;
      height:110px;
    }
    
    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }
    
    ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 36%;
    margin-top: 22px;
} 

  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      margin: auto;
      min-height:200px;
  }

  /* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  </style>
  

</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="its.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="service.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div data-carousel-3d >

<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-3D-Rotating-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-carousel-3d//images/left.png" data-carousel-3d-left />
    <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-3D-Rotating-Carousel-Plugin-For-jQuery-carousel-3d/images/right.png" data-carousel-3d-right />


        <ul data-carousel-3d-children>
          <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=628" /></li>
          <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=635" /></li>
          <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=633" /></li>
          <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=635" /></li>
          <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=626" /></li>
          <li selected><img src="https://unsplash.it/640/420?image=629" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

          <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <h3>Welcome to IT Spectra</h3><br>
            <p id="ccont">IT Spectra excels in providing custom software and
              mobile apps that match your specications, which is
              just one of its many advantages: Extensive Team of experienced
              professionals. 15+ years of IT experience.
              Unique Ideas Expand skilled resources. Well within
              budget and time constraints. Gain competitive advantage
              in the market..</p>
          </div>
      
    


          
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="about">
             <h2>About Us</h2>
              <p id="fcont">IT Spectra excels in providing
               custom software and mobile apps
               that match your specifications,
               which is just one of its many
               advantages</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
 
 
 
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="services">
          <h2>Company</h2>
            <p id="fcont">Company Overview
              Meet The Team
              Our Awesome Partners
              Our Services</p>
          </div>
       </div> 
       </div>
       </div>
 
 
 
 
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="contact">
                    <h2>Address</h2>
                     <p>IT SPECTRA<br/>
                     Flat-1A,1st Floor,<br/>
                     Plot No.38,James Street,<br/>
                     Ram Nagar-North,<br/>
                     Madippakkam,Chennai-91.</br>
                     Phone : 044 - 4957 7990<br/>
                     E-mail : info@itspectra.com<br/>
                     Web : www.itspectra</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
 
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reduce the padding.

Comment: even i remove padding its not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reduce the height of the nav bar?

If so then you can use the following css override:

```
.navbar {
   height: auto !important;
}
```